# How factory pattern is applied in opening a link from any mail

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, abstract, factory-pattern

When we open a link from outlook or gmail, it opens up in browser.
Is there any kind of design pattern involved in it?
Is Factory pattern or Abstract factory pattern applied in this if yes i want to know how?
Any knowledge sharing will be appreciated.

Comment: @trincot could you share your view on this. It will be helpful if you have something to share.

Comment: The factory pattern is related to creation of instances of objects with different properties , in clicking a link which will open a browser, the browser just receive link and open it, I don't see a instances creation operation here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are instances of the strategy pattern and factory pattern involved when you open a link from your email client.

First the url scheme is inspected (https:, email:, etc.), and some kind of handler for opening links of that type is looked up from configuration. The client then delegates to this handler to open the link. (strategy pattern)

For http: or https: links, the handler instantiates the system's default web browser (factory pattern) and tells it to open the URL.

The details are quite involved and vary between OSes, but in general terms it always works like this.

Comment: is Opening some file using "Open with" option also same as the above means there is also Factory Design pattern involved in it?

Comment: "Open with" doesn't really follow the factory pattern, since the type of object to create is chosen specifically.